how to display a pdf in iframe from a private disk storage in Laravel 11?
how to display a pdf in iframe from a private disk storage in Laravel 11?
'private' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
            'visibility' => 'private',
        ],

Tried $path = Storage::disk('private')->path($filename);

I used this workaround before and its working well for me, its all about creating a new route for viewing the pdf then use it at your iframe as src
here is the code of the new route controller function
file = Storage::disk('private')->get($file_path);
    
return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

So as example you can create a new route let's say
⁠"/view-pdf/{file_path}"

and at the function of this route use the code I mentioned above, then use this route at src attribute of the iframe

It's returning 404.

Can you please share with me how do you defined the route at web.php and share me the code of your controller function, and how you used the route at iframe src attribute?
